# Sql Query in Linq

Tags: linq

i need to write sql query in string and pass it to linq like executenonquery() in ado.net
but i need to return data from 4 tables 
Example Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.GeneralAd INNER JOIN
dbo.Category ON dbo.GeneralAd.FkCategoryID = dbo.Category.CategoryID INNER JOIN
dbo.District ON dbo.GeneralAd.FkDistrictID = dbo.District.DistrictID LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Users ON dbo.GeneralAd.FkApprovedByID = dbo.Users.UserID AND dbo.GeneralAd.FKAddedByID = dbo.Users.UserID where .........
```

---

how to return data from 4 tables with executenonquery method in linq ?

Comment: You wouldn't use `ExecuteNonQuery()` since it doesn't return a result set. Also you can probably write this as a LINQ query without passing explicit SQL statements.

Comment: what @Yuck said is right and use `var` keyword to relief yourself from the return type (even though, it is `IQueryable<T>` usually).

Comment: ok, how can i write if statment when using var keyword ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you why you want to return all columns from all tables.  That seems unnecessary.  You can get to the District and Category fields from the GeneralAd object.

What I would probably do is define a property on the General Ad object that executes a select to get the associated User.

If you did want to do it in Linq, you could use something like this:

```
var results = (from ga in DataContext.GeneralAds
               select new 
               { 
                   Col1 = ga.Col1,
                   Col2 = ga.Category.Col2,
                   Col3 = ga.District.Col3,
                   Col4 = (from u in DataContext.Users
                           where u.UserID = ga.FkApprovedByID AND u.UserID = ga.FKAddedByID
                           select u.Col4)
               });
```

You might have to add an Any() method on Col4:

```
var results = (from ga in DataContext.GeneralAds
               select new 
               { 
                   Col1 = ga.Col1,
                   Col2 = ga.Category.Col2,
                   Col3 = ga.District.Col3,
                   Col4 = ((from u in DataContext.Users
                            where u.UserID = ga.FkApprovedByID AND u.UserID = ga.FKAddedByID
                            select u.Col4).Any() ? 
                              (from u in DataContext.Users
                               where u.UserID = ga.FkApprovedByID AND u.UserID = ga.FKAddedByID
                               select u.Col4).First() : -1)
               });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i donn't want to return all column , it's just example , i need to write if statments in query when search as there are more combinations and that cause poor performance , query will be like that : declare @x varchar(max) set @x = ' SELECT * FROM dbo.GeneralAd INNER JOIN..... WHERE 1 = 1 ' IF (@TITLE != '') begin Set @x = @x + 'AND Title Like %' + @TITLE + '%' END IF (@FkADDedBy != -1) begin set @x =@x + ' AND FKAddedbyID = ' + @FKADDedBy end if( @District != -1).. exec(@x) i need to write this query as string in C# rather than @X and pass this query to link

Comment: if i can't make it as sql query , how can i write if statment in var keyword .

Comment: This would be much better in LINQ.  Since LINQ builds the query and executes at the last moment, it will build everything for you and you don't have to include anything unnecessary.  Check out my post here:  http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/linq-for-search-queries-with-multiple-optional-parameters/